# Website is not properly zooming out on some computers

Tags: html, css

I have recently designed my new website & when I'm zooming out from some computers, some elements are messing up. Please give a solution for this.

Website url : http://www.amazingadvertise.com/web_templates/businesscard

Website's second 12 logos are messing up. Those logos are moving to the left hand side & when resetting zoom, it's not centering to the page.

Comment: What kind of OS & browser version ?

Comment: Your best bet is a responsive design using `%` and or `em`, but it is tough to style for all sizes, especially when zooming in & out using the browser

Answer (score 0):

One reason is because you have a margin-left on your divs such as .testing. If you want this to get applied then it's best to put that inside a media-query with min-width. 
But as @Adjit said it's tough to account for people who are zooming in and out.